# Finding max field value in mongodb using node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new in mongodb and node. I am trying to find the max value for a field (userId). But it returns nothing.

My code is

```
EventSchema.static("createUser",function(event,user,callback){

    var That = this;

    var max_usr_Id = '';

    async.waterfall([

        function(callback) {

            That.find({"userId" : {"$ne" : ""}, "$and" : [{"userId" : {"$exists" : 1}}]}).sort({"_id" : -1}).limit(1).select("userId").exec(function(err, doc)
            {
                if(err)
                {
                    console.log('User ID ERROR-');
                    callback({error:err,message:"Error getting max User ID"});
                }else {
                    console.log('User ID-');
                    console.log(doc.userId);
                    max_usr_Id = doc.userId;
                    console.log(max_usr_Id);
                }
            });

            console.log(max_usr_Id);

        },
});
```

For some reason the control doesn't go inside the find function. When I try the following query in mongodb shell it works.

```
db.users.find({ 
    "userId" : {
        "$ne" : ""
    }, 
    "$and" : [
        {
            "userId" : {
                "$exists" : true
            }
        }
    ]
}).sort({ 
    "_id" : -1.0
}).limit(1);
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `$and` operation is not properly written, take a look at the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla I have changed {"$exists" : 1} to {"$exists" : true} but still it gives nothing.

Comment: That was not what I was pointing at, let me post an answer with the relevant change (I think) you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$and` is not used in the proper way, try with:

```
That.find({ $and: [ 
              { "userId": { $ne: "" } },
              { "userId": { $exists: true } } 
            ] }).sort( ...
```

Take a look at the [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) documentation.

**Edit**

After seen the comments, the problem must be in the way the logging is made. You need to call `toArray` to get a collection, and then iterate over it (with `forEach` for instance):

```
...find( ... ).toArray(function(err, docs) {

    // Print each document returned
    docs.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.userId);
    });

});
```

Comment: Nice. I can see the userId coming inside the doc. But when I do console.log(doc.userId) then it prints "undefined".

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra Try removing all chained methods, start with just the `find` and check if returns the documents, then add the `sort` and repeat the check, and so on. My guess will be that the `select` is not working.

Comment: The doc is coming like this - `[ { _id: 5a6f5c49355d6775d47b8a36, userId: '161257' } ]` but when I do `console.log(doc.userId)` then it prints `undefined`. Strange.

Comment: 1) Where do you see the doc like that?? 2) Did you remove all chained methods and execute just with the `find`?

Comment: 1) In the console so I think the select works. 2)Yes I have removed all the methods and just executed find and I can see all the documents in the console.

Comment: ahh the mistake is the field value for userId is Int32 in collection whereas the field defined in the schema is string.

Comment: I just saw your edited comments. It is returning only one row so is it needed to have iteration.